# Forwarding onActivityResult from Activity to Fragment in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, android-activity, facebook-login

I am trying to implement Facebook login for my android app. However, instead of using the LoginActivity, as suggested on the developer [website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.2), I have added the Facebook login button on a separate fragment. This fragment simply holds the button and does all the processing, which otherwise the LoginActivity would have done.
The purpose of using a separate fragment is to prevent doing everything in the LoginActivity, specially if other login options like Google+ also exist.

Now the problem is that the UiLifecycleHelper constructor accepts only Activity object for callbacks:

```
UiLifecycleHelper(Activity, StatusCallback)
```

Because of this, I am bound to do something like:

```
UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback)
```

So, eventually:

```
@override
onActivityResult(...)
```

is called in LoginActivity, instead of in my fragment which hosts the login button.

Now the authentication won't work, unless I explicitly call `onActivityResult` method in the fragment from `onActivityResult` from the `LoginActivity`. Because it is the fragment who has created and is maintaining the UILifecycleHelper object.

I want to avoid adding this "hack" in the `LoginActivity`, specially since, there's no way for me to know if the `onActivityResult` was called as a result of Facebook authentication process.

What's a proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they recognized this problem in the new Facebook SDK (v 4.0 onwards) and they now let you register a fragment on the LoginButton.
Following is the code snippet from the official [Facebook Login For Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3) guide.

```
 // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
```